# Can scp copy directories recursively?

Tags: linux, scp

Currently I can only copy a single `.tar` file. But how can I copy directories recursively with `scp`?

Answer (score 1286, accepted):

Yup, use `-r`:

```
scp -rp sourcedirectory user@dest:/path
```

- -r means recursive
- -p preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.

Note: This creates the `sourcedirectory` inside `/path` thus the files will be in `/path/sourcedirectory`

Comment: However bear in mind that this won't preserve symlinks.

Comment: Note that `-pr` (options in reversed order) won't copy the folders, bur rather their content to the target directory (apparently, the order of options matters).

Comment: If I do a ./ to do the current directory it says Error: unexpected file name. I know I can go to the parent directory and do it that way, or use globing with *. However, I am curious why ./ would not work for the source directory?

Answer (score 217):

While the previous answers are technically correct, you should also consider using [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) instead.  `rsync` compares the data on the sending and receiving sides with a diff mechanism so it doesn't have to resend data that was already previously sent.

If you are going to copy something to a remote machine more than once, use `rsync`.  Actually, it's good to use `rsync` every time because it has more controls for things like copying file permissions and ownership and excluding certain files or directories.  In general:

```
$ rsync -av /local/dir/ server:/remote/dir/
```

will synchronize a local directory with a remote directory.  If you run it a second time and the contents of the local directory haven't changed, no data will be transferred - much more efficient than running `scp` and copying everything every time.

Also, `rsync` allows you to recover from interrupted transfers very easily, unlike `scp`.

Finally, modern versions of `rsync` by default run over ssh, so if `scp` is already working, `rsync` should pretty much be a drop-in replacement.

Comment: I agree `rsync` is more efficient. One thing it doesn't currently do that `scp` does is allow copying between remote hosts (at least without running the rsync client on one of them).

Comment: `-av` :v is for verbose, a for archive and is a shortcut to -rlptgoD  which implies recursive , preserve rights owner dates and links. If you only want recursive use `-r`

Comment: rsync does not encrpyt traffic, so you need to use extra "-e ssh" to encrypt the traffic like scp

Answer (score 38):

That is what the `-r` option is for. :)

See the [scp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) for more info if needed.

Answer (score 20):

Recursive Copy Option '-r' (lower case)

```
scp -r
```

Which I confuse with the regular local recursive copy option '-R' (upper case)

```
cp -R
```

Comment: I just wanted to point out the difference between cp and scp as -r and -R are not the same. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18712/difference-between-cp-r-and-cp-r-copy-command

Answer (score 18):

The best way is to use rsync over SSH

```
rsync -a -essh /source/ user@dest-server:/dest/

rsync -a -essh user@source-server:/source/ /dest/
```

My favorites options are -Pazvessh --delete :

- -a : archive mode (include a lot of default common options, including preserving symlinks)
- -z : compress
- -v : verbose : show files
- -P : show progess as files done/remaining files
- -e ssh : do rsync in ssh protocol
- --delete : delete files in the destination that are not anymore in the source

Comment: All versions of `rsync` that I have used would use `ssh` by default, so `-essh` is unlikely to be needed. And the choice of command used to connect to the remote host is really unrelated to copying recursively.

Answer (score 8):

After looking for the recursive copy flag, and successfully used it thanks to this post, I would like to post just a suggestion.

If the case is that you are copying (recursively) a directory. Maybe if the files are sent compressed you could save time in the transfer

What I did in the end was:

```
local$ tar -czvf local.tar.gz directory/
local$ scp local.tar.gz user@remote:/directory
ssh user@remote
remote$ tar -xzvf local.tar.gz
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the file extension should be either `.tar.gz` or `.tgz` since the file is a gzipped tar archive (since the `-z` flag is used).

Answer (score 4):

You can recursively copy a directory into a compressed archive with this simple command:

```
ssh -p 22 user@address-to-copy-from.com  'cd /parent/directory && tar zcvf - directory_to_copy' > /destination/on/your/machine/archive_name.tgz
```

For example, to copy contents of `/var/log` from `domain.com` to `~/logs.tgz` you run:

```
ssh -p 22 user@domain.com  'cd /var && tar zcvf - log' > ~/logs.tgz
```

You can also extract files on target system by using pipes. This command will copy contents of `/var/log` at `domain.com` to `~/destination/log` on your system:

```
ssh -p 22 user@domain.com  'cd /var && tar zcvf - log' | tar xzf - -C ~/destination
```

Though to mirror a directory, you probably should use `rsync`...

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to pass the user's password as a parameter rather than inputting it interactively, you can use `sshpass` (`sudo apt-get install -y sshpass`).

Example:

```
sshpass -p 'remote_password' scp -rp /src/folder myremoteusername@122.10.12.123:/dest/folder
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use -r option with scp command to copy directories recursively on any system. If you need anything else refer [scp command tutorial](https://linux4one.com/how-to-use-scp-command-to-transfer-files-folders-in-linux/). -r option stands for recursive operation in most of the Linux commands.

Comment: While true, the `-r` option has already been suggested years ago and is the accepted answer.